# Парсинг одинаковых тегов

Tags: delphi-7

Доброго времени суток!
На хтмл-странице, которая открыта в `webbrowser`, много одинаковых тегов `<b></b>`. Нужно записать в мемо значения 1 и 10 тегов или 2 и 11. Подскажите, как сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давно не работал с делфи, но навскидку могу сказать, что будет как-тот так:

```
<b for="b1">текст1</b>
<b for="b2">текст2</b>
<b for="b3">текст3</b>
...
<b for="b150">текст300</b>
```

Работаем с таким кодом так:

```
...
var Element2: OleVariant;
begin
  Doc:=(WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).all.tags('b') as IHTMLElementCollection;
  Element2:=Doc.item(i,0)as IHTMLLabelElement; 
  Memo1.Items.Add(Element2.innerText); 
  ShowMessage(Element2.htmlFor);
end;
```

Как-то так вроде... Не проверял, но должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что надо!!!